# Programmatically set value in Quasar Select Drop Down

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Quasar and have the following code:

```
<q-select
    rounded
    outlined
    bottom-slots
    stack-label
    :dense="dense"
    v-model="sexSelected"
    :options="sexOptions"
    option-value="value"
    label="Sex"
    class="mystyle"
    map-options
  />
```

My sexOption is:

```
 sexOptions:[ {
            label: 'Both Sexes',
            value: '0'
          },
          {
            label: 'Male',
            value: '1'
          },
          {
            label: 'Female',
            value: '2'
          }],
```

Based upon the value an end users selects in a different select I need to select programmatically either Male or Female.

I have tried:

```
 this.sexSelected.value = "2" 

 this.sexSelected = "Female'

 this.sexSelected = [{label: 'Female', value: '2' }]
```

Comment: How about `this.sexSelected = "2"` ?

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of different combinations this worked for both the display and the value

```
this.sexSelected = ({
        label: 'Female',
        value: '2'
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with single selects/dropdowns, you should always keep in mind that behind the scene only the value is used and not the label/name (what the user sees), so basically try each of the ways to set only the value, not the label

```
this.sexSelected.value = "2";
this.sexSelected.value = 2;

this.sexSelected = "2";
this.sexSelected = 2;
```

one of these should work

Comment: Using this.sexSelected.value = "2"  changes the value of the drop down but not the display.  Using this.sexSelected = "2" changes the display but not value so if I use the value I get an undefined.  If I use both at the same time one after the other I get an undefined